# How can I only select the newest entries from a table

Tags: t-sql

i have a table with jobs like this in a MS SQL Server 2008 database:

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
J_ID      J_Name       J_ReadDate                  J_I_ID
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
01        Job1        2011-06-26 01:00:12.153      1
02        Job2        2011-06-25 01:00:07.103      1
03        Job3        2011-06-25 01:00:07.103      2
04        Job4        2011-06-25 01:00:07.103      3
05        Job1        2011-06-26 01:00:07.103      1
06        Job2        2011-06-26 01:00:08.103      2
07        Job1        2011-06-26 01:00:08.103      2
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

now i want to select only the newest jobs, no matter how old the entry is. So in my example it would like to get this result (ordered by J_ReadDate DESC):

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
J_ID      J_Name       J_ReadDate                  J_I_ID
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
06        Job2        2011-06-26 01:00:08.103      2
07        Job1        2011-06-26 01:00:08.103      2
05        Job1        2011-06-26 01:00:07.103      1
03        Job3        2011-06-25 01:00:07.103      2
04        Job4        2011-06-25 01:00:07.103      3
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

how can I achieve this? I cannot say, that the time difference between the entries is always one day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below will get what you're after.

```
SELECT J_ID, J_Name, J_ReadDate, J_I_ID
FROM (
  SELECT J_ID, J_Name, J_ReadDate, J_I_ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY J_Name ORDER BY J_ReadDate DESC) AS RN
  FROM jobs
) J
WHERE J.RN = 1
ORDER BY J_ReadDate DESC
```

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention something... J_Name is not unique, so deciding on this column is not enough. In my case the combination of J_Name and J_I_ID is unique (together with the time), can I simply add J_I_ID to the partition clause?

Comment: @Fender: You might probably have determined it by yourself, but for the sake of those reading this thread later on: Yes, you can.